# Icons are grabbed with mouse without clicking

Tags: mouse, icons

When I choose icons from the sidebar of file manager, the mouse grabs this icon without any additional clicking.

Also, when I run [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/), the Freecad environment is still rotating with the mouse without doing any click.

[image]

Comment: Is Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Tap to click on?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Tap to click`